# Restoring broken Windows 10 and programs from Windows.old folder

Tags: windows-10, repair-install, windows.old

My dad's UX51VZ laptop crashed (likely due to incorrect BIOS setting at repair shop) and would no longer boot. [I tried repairing the install and the MBR but nothing worked](https://superuser.com/questions/1810492/repairing-windows-installation-that-cant-boot), so I installed Windows 10 again. To my surprise it didn't format the drive, but put the old windows and program files in a "Windows.old" folder.

Now that I have a booting Windows is there any way to recover or merge the Windows.old into the new install (or find and fix the problems in Windows.old) **so I don't have to reinstall all the programs**?

I don't seem to have the option to "Go back to the previous version of Windows 10" under "Settings > Update & Security > Recovery."

I also do not see the option when trying this:

> At the Sign In screen, hold down the shift key on your keyboard while
> clicking the Power button on the screen Continue to hold down the
> shift key while clicking Restart Continue to hold down the shift key
> until the Advanced Recovery Options menu appears Click Troubleshoot
> Click Advanced options Click Go back to the previous version of
> Windows

Comment: Unfortunately you will need to reinstall all the programs anew.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't even see the option to roll back. Could I look into fixing the Windows.old? Even if I do, how would I restore it?

Comment: @Flyview - What you want is not possible, your previous installation isn’t functional, John’s advice only applies to a functional Windows installation. You will need to simply reinstall any application you wish to have